# Fetch all Episerver Blocks/Type/Usages programmatically

Tags: episerver, episerver-8

I am trying to create custom report for Blocks list and usages int pages. So I need to get all list of block types available and the usages/links in pages.

I have tried the below code but this requires Block as input to fetch usages.

```
        var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
            var contentTypeRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentTypeRepository>();
            var contentModelUsage = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentModelUsage>();
            var myblockType = contentTypeRepository.Load<InputBlock>();
            List<ContentReference> myblockTypeReferences = contentModelUsage.ListContentOfContentType(myblockType).Select(x => x.ContentLink.ToReferenceWithoutVersion()).Distinct().ToList();
            InputBlock blockType;
            foreach (ContentReference cref in myblockTypeReferences)
            {
                repository.TryGet<InputBlock>(cref, out blockType);
                model.lstBlocks.Add(blockType);                    
            }
```

I expect to not provide input block and get all list of block types available in Episerver and usages in pages

Comment: Not sure I understand the question entirely, but you can use `IContentTypeRepository .List()` to get _all_ content types.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop through all the content types and then loop through usages of all those content types. I used below function in Epi 11

```
    public IList<IContent> GetUnusedBlocks()
    {
        var contentTypeRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentTypeRepository>();
        var contentModelUsage = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentModelUsage>();
        var contentRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
        var linkRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentSoftLinkRepository>();

        var unusedBlocks = new List<IContent>();

        // Loop through all content types
        foreach (var contentType in contentTypeRepository.List().Where(content => content.Name.ToLower().Contains("block")))
        {
            // Find usages of the content type in question
            IList<ContentUsage> contentUsages = contentModelUsage.ListContentOfContentType(contentType);

            // Get usages including versions
            IList<IContent> blocks = contentUsages.Select(contentUsage =>
                contentUsage.ContentLink.ToReferenceWithoutVersion())
                .Distinct()
                .Select(contentReference => contentRepository.Get<IContent>(contentReference))
                .ToList();

            // Find blocks that are being referenced
            foreach (IContent block in blocks)
            {
                var referencingContentLinks = linkRepository.Load(block.ContentLink, true)
                    .Where(link =>
                            link.SoftLinkType == ReferenceType.PageLinkReference &&
                            !ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(link.OwnerContentLink))
                    .Select(link => link.OwnerContentLink);

                if (!referencingContentLinks.Any())
                {
                    unusedBlocks.Add(block);
                }
            }
        }
        return unusedBlocks;
    }
```

Reference: [EpiServer - How can I find out if a block is being used on any published page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454291/episerver-how-can-i-find-out-if-a-block-is-being-used-on-any-published-page)

Comment: and same rhetoric that every body fancies alot: use constructor DI

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the Content Types, you can IContentRespository List() method.

To get actual instances of content, you can use IContentModelUsage ListContentOfContentType method. That will grab all the instances.

```
var usages = contentModelUsage.ListContentOfContentType(contentType);
```

There is also a free app in Episerver's new App Marketplace that I think does something similar to the functionality you are seeking if you want to [check it out](https://marketplace.episerver.com/apps/nansen/content-usage-finder/).

edit: I see you tagged this with Episerver 8, and the app is only with 11 and above, so that may not work for you.